# Adding button and textbox dynamically in jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

```
<form:form action="approveAccount.html" method="GET">
<input type="submit" value="approvAll"/>
<p>Following Accounts are Pending to approve</p>    
<c:forEach items="${accountIdList}" var="val">
<li>${val}</li>                               
</c:forEach>        
</form:form>
```

val is the value that is fetched from database, I want to add a submit button and want to use this fetched value to do some stuffs, how many value get fetched is dynamically decided, how todo that.. here in this scenario, I am getting account id which admin needs to approv, so by adding textbox, admin can assign the role to the this account and then submit the to the database and this all happen with that clk of button

Comment: As per my understand you want to create submit button from fetched data. Am i correct?

Comment: yes want to create submit button, so that i can use this fetched value, do some stuff and then submit in database

Comment: Then use <input type="submit"> in place of <li>. What issue your getting on this.

Comment: i edited my question, telling the exact scenario, could u plz go thru it, and let me knw the way for this ..

Comment: Still it is not very clear

Comment: Look at my answer. I have tried to create `textfield` & `button` dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, in your service class, you have *list of accountIds* like this

```
ArrayList<Integer> accountIdList = new ArrayList<>();
accountIdList.add(1);
accountIdList.add(2);
accountIdList.add(3);
```

& you have added this list into *HTTP Session* object for further use like

```
session.setAttribute("accountIds",accountIdList);
```

In your JSP, you can then use `JSTL for-each loop` to create dynamic buttons & textboxes as below

```
<c:forEach var="ids" items="${session.accountIds}" varStatus="loop">
    <input type="text" name="role${loop.index}" />
    <input type="submit" value="<c:out value=${ids} />" /> 
</c:forEach>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, your trying to get multiple ids and it's associated roles when the user click submit button. You can try the following to get them:

JSP:

```
<form:form action="approveAccount.html" method="GET">
  <input type="submit" value="approvAll"/>
  <p>Following Accounts are Pending to approve</p>    
  <c:forEach items="${accountIdList}" var="val">
    <input type="text" value="${val}" name="id"> 
    <select name="role">
        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
        <option value="user">user</option>
    </select>                              
  </c:forEach>        
</form:form>
```

Servlet:

```
String [] txt = request.getParameterValues("id");
String [] role = request.getParameterValues("role");

for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; i++){
    System.out.println(txt[i]+" "+role[i]);
}
```